# Как отключить "тень" при свайпе?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, android-scrollview

Когда тянешь пальцем экран вертикально, дотягиваешь до края и тянешь дальше, начинает проявляться полукруглая тень. Есть ли возможность её отключить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл ответ.

В `ScrollView`:

```
android:overScrollMode="never"
```